# Can a sum score of binary items be used for correlational analysis in the same way as likert scales?

Tags: correlation, survey, likert

I'm wondering if you can use parametric analysis with scores made from binary responses in the same way that you can for likert scales.

Just to illustrate with an example: Say I created a survey where the respondents where asked 10 simple yes/no (1/0) questions about their experience using different drugs, with the same question for 10 different drugs. For instance; "Have you used cocain during the last 3 months?" 
If I made a sumscore called "Number of different drugs used in the last 3 months" based on the amount of "yes" answers given by each respondent. Could I then use that score in the same way as a likert scale and run parametric tests? And if not, why not? Is there a better way to analyse this type of data re: correlational analysis.

And I apologise if my English is not very good, please ask me if anything is confusing.

Thank you very much for any help or resources.

Comment: Using the sum implies that you consider use of each of the 10 drugs to be equally important. I don't have your list of drugs to form my own opinion on this, but I'd be surprised if you would want to argue that the drugs are equally important for your purposes. Also you don't say what hypotheses you would want to test using these sums. // If your subjects are randomly chosen from a population of interest, then perhaps it is worthwhile using a chi-squared test to see if drugs are about equally 'popular', or if some drugs stand out as most used.

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea in the second part of my Comment, suppose you
have $n=100$ subjects and a $10$-vector contains usage counts
for each of the ten drugs, as in the hypothetical data sampled below
using R.  The simulation assumes drugs have probabilities `p` of use from
$0.1$ to $0.3.$

```
set.seed(2020)
p = c(10,10,10,10,10, 15,15,25,25,30)/100;  p
[1] 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.10 0.15 0.15 0.25 0.25 0.30
use=rbinom(1000, 1, p)   # 1000 subject responses
MAT=matrix(use, byrow=T, nrow=100)
dim(MAT)
[1] 100  10  # 100 by 10 matrix, each row for a subject
drug.f = colSums(MAT);  drug.f
[1]  9  7 11 12  9 15 18 26 17 26  # freq of use for drugs

chisq.test(drug.f)

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  drug.f
X-squared = 27.733, df = 9, p-value = 0.001057
```

The null hypothesis is that the ten drugs are used with equal
frequency. [This is assumed by `chisq.test` unless another
null hypothesis is stated.]

The null hypothesis is rejected. *Ad hoc* tests can show which
drugs are used significantly more often than others. These *ad hoc*
tests should use P-values below 5% according to the Bonferroni
method of avoiding false discovery.

For example, below we compare reported frequencies of use for Drug 1 and Drug 10. (The null hypothesis that the two drugs are equally likely choices for these subjects is strongly rejected.)

```
prop.test(c(9,26), c(100,100))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(9, 26) out of c(100, 100)
X-squared = 8.8658, df = 1, p-value = 0.002906
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
  -0.28265048 -0.05734952
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.09   0.26
```

*Note:* If you want to test something using sums of number of drugs used for each subject, here is a summary of the 100 subject sums
for my simulated data.

```
subj.sum = rowSums(MAT)
table(subj.sum)
subj.sum
 0  1  2  3  4 
16 39 29 11  5
```

For what it's worth, you could test the null hypothesis that sum is centered at 2 drugs per subject or above, using a one-sample Wilcoxon (signed rank) test. (Rejected with a P-value near $0.)$

```
wilcox.test(subj.sum, mu = 2, alte="less")


        Wilcoxon signed rank test 
        with continuity correction

data:  subj.sum
V = 585.5, p-value = 1.587e-05
alternative hypothesis: true location is less than 2
```